# How can I center the logo when 750 screen size is meet?

Tags: html, css

I want to center the logo when it meets the media screen size [(See Photo Here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnB2F.png):

[image]

My code is:

```css
.logo img {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class='nav-bar'>
    <li class='logo'>
      <a href="#" style="float: left;"><img src="{{ section.settings.logo | img_url }}"></a>
    </li>
    <ul>
      <nav>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; you open a `<ul>` (I assume a typo, and you probably meant to close the existing element instead). Also, where did you get stuck? You're floating the parent element (the `<a>` left with inline styles, which takes priority over a stylesheet), which is therefore likely to prevent/complicate a centering of the `<img>`.

Comment: What have you tried to do that? What problems did you have doing that with media queries?

Answer (score 0):

To center the logo when the screen size meets the media query breakpoint, you can use CSS Flexbox. Here's an example code:

```
    .logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 125px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .logo {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: far too "complicated"  for an issue that can be solved with one property. The is no effect in using `align-items: center` when there is no height larger than `fit-content`. Also, no reason to implement a specific media query rule when it contains the previous set behavior anyways.

Answer (score 0):

remove `float` from the anchor and then simply center the anchor by using `text-align: center` on the wrapping li (`.logo`):

```css
.logo img {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 125px;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class='nav-bar'>
    <li class='logo'>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/125.jpg"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```